# Sort elements as part of concatenating elements of 2 Lists

Tags: scala

Here is a function I wrote for concatenating elements of a List using an accumulator with tail recursion :

```
val l1 = List(1, 2, 3)                          //> l1  : List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
  val l2 = List(1, 2, 3)                          //> l2  : List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

  def func(l1: List[Int], l2: List[Int], acc: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    (l1, l2) match {
      case (Nil, Nil) => acc.reverse
      case (h1 :: t1, h2 :: t2) => {
        func(t1, t2, h1 :: h2 :: acc)
      }
    }
  }                                               //> func: (l1: List[Int], l2: List[Int], acc: List[Int])List[Int]

  func(l1, l2, List())                            //> res0: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
```

This is my understanding of the call order

```
  func( 1 :: 1 :: () )
  func( 2 :: 2 :: 1 :: 1 : () )
  func( 3 :: 3 :: 2 :: 2 :: 1 :: 1 : () )
```

So the call order is the reason why I must call `reverse` on base call of acc so that the List is ordered in same ordering initial List elements. To try to minimize the steps required to concatenate the lists I have tried to add the elements like this :

```
func(t1, t2, acc :: h1 :: h2)
```

instead of

```
func(t1, t2, h1 :: h2 :: acc)
```

but receive compile time error :

value :: is not a member of Int

So it seems I cannot prepend these elements to this List ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `x :: y`, `y` must be a list and `x` the element you want to prepend.

You can use `acc :+ h1 :+ h2` to append `h1` and `h2` to `acc`, but note that adding elements to the end of the list is a relatively expensive operation (linear with the length of the list).